# strcmp() function in C

Tags: c, strcmp

I'm using the strcmp() fucntions to test how it works.

Ok,there is strcmp(string1,string2) that says us is ti string1 greater or smaller than string2 .

Here is my code to test this function:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
 char string1[20];
 char string2[20];
int main()
{
    int test;

    printf("Enter 'string1'\n");
    scanf("%s",&string1);
    printf("Enter 'string2'\n");
    scanf("%s",&string2);

    test=strcmp(string1,string2);

    if(test>0)
        printf("String 'string1' is greater than 'string2'\n");
    else if(test<0)
        printf("String 'string1' is less than 'string2'\n");
    else if(test==0)
        printf("\n String 'string1'is equal to 'string2'");

        printf("\n The value of 'test' is :%d",test);

        return 0;
}
```

the test variable is always 1 and 'string1' is always greater than 'string2' .
pls help

Comment: `scanf("%s",&string1);`  -> `scanf("%s",string1);`, same for `string2`

Comment: Can we make a rule that a MCVE does not use `scanf` unless the question is specifically about `scanf`?  Or just user-input in general.  If you want to experiment with `strcmp`, try using hard-coded strings that you know are good rather than adding another thing that can go wrong.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons in this particular case the problem IS in usage of `scanf`.

Comment: `scanf("%s",&string1);` isn't that the same thing as `scanf("%s",string1);` for arrays? (although the second is the proper way)

Comment: @SergeyA That's my point.  The question is asking about the behavior of `strcmp`, but the error was in `scanf` instead.  Seems to be a lot of questions asking about the behavior of one thing, only for the problem to be in taking user input.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre The values will probably be the same but not the types, so the compiler is free to do strange things.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons I have tried this on meta that didn't went well: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/364431/add-a-no-interactive-code-warning-on-the-mcve-help-page

Comment: anyway: OP is stating that `strcmp` doesn't work...

Comment: Using `&` certainly won't be the same if the array is a function argument.

Comment: Start by assigning known values to `string1` and `string2` directly and not using `scanf` at all.  IOW, do something like `char string1[20] = "foo"; char string2[20] = "bar"; int test = strcmp( string1, string2 );...`.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre That's a shame.  Well now it's only voted down to -7.

Comment: What is the **exact** input you're giving to the program?

Comment: @ChristianGibbons call to scanf do invoke UB here but there's a pretty good chance the compiler actually did what OP expected it to do. I haven't seen a compiler that would do something nasty/unexpected here. We don't know what inputs OP has tested though. Perhaps the problem is in the input data itself. If so, fixing scanf woildn't help.

Comment: @dbush: That is unlikely to be the cause of the problem. Likely in whatever C implementation OP is using, the address of the array is the same as the address of its first character.

Comment: @n.m. But having hard-coded values instead of `scanf` would further help as it would give us the test data.

Comment: OP’s program works as expected for me. I suspect their input is not being interpreted by `scanf` in the way they expect. An MCVE including input is required.

Comment: Please provide the exact inputs as requested by @dbush.

Comment: And please have the program print what it reads so that you can see that it is working on the data you think it is working on.

Answer (score 1):

`strcmp` is unlikely the problem. Here are a few things you can do to troubleshoot the problem.

1. Make sure to prevent overflow when using `scanf`.
2. Make sure that the calls to `scanf` are successful.
3. Add a line of code to print what was read so you know the values being passed to `strcmp`.
4. You don't need to use `&string1` to read a string. Use just `string1`. Same with `string2`.

---

```
printf("Enter 'string1'\n");

// Read at most 19 characters from the stream, leaving space
// for the null terminator.

if ( scanf("%19s", string1) != 1 )
{
   // Problem reading into string1.
   printf("Unable to read string1\n");
}

printf("Enter 'string2'\n");
if ( scanf("%19s", string2) != 1 )
{
   // Problem reading into string2.
   printf("Unable to read string2\n");
}

printf("Input strings...\nstring1: \"%s\", string2: \"%s\"\n", string1, string2);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should write like this, because the problem is in the `scanf`:

```
printf("Enter 'string1'\n");
scanf("%s",string1);
printf("Enter 'string2'\n");
scanf("%s",string2);
```

Don't use the  `&` when you try read a string/pointer.

E.g:

```
char *str;
scanf("%s", str);
```

You can use the `fread(string1, 20, stdin)` to previne the string overflow

You can try the code [here](https://ideone.com/45toWA)

Comment: Not my DV, but the space before `%s` is not necessary, since the `%s` format filters whitespace anyway (as does `%d` format). It might need to be before `%c` format or `%[]` format specs. It doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Yeah, but I like always clean the buffer

Comment: While it is not proper to pass a pointer to an array of `char` to `scanf` when scanning a string, it is unlikely to be the cause of OP’s problem.

Comment: @WeatherVane I did not answer the question?

Comment: The above comment from @EricPostpischil says it is unlikely to be the cause of the problem. My compilation of the code works as expected, although my inputs are < 20 length and contain no spaces.

Comment: You can also avoid buffer overrun with `scanf("%19s", str);`.

Comment: I already do this but I'm geting the same problem.Maybe i can try with fread(string1, 20, stdin) but thats not the point.

Comment: @tarik Put the printscreen please, it's impossible, look that https://ideone.com/45toWA

Comment: here it is the link :https://ibb.co/mHaJO9

Comment: @tarik the code is right, the problem is that you dont know how the function strcmp() works, look at this https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/library-function/string.h/strcmp  The strcmp() goes from character to character and compares which is greater (ascii table)

Comment: @FábioMorais Thank you very much for this article,now I know how the comparison work but i don't know how I always get '1' or '-1' ,for example if i compare 'a' with 'A' i must to get the value 32 not -1 or 1

Comment: that's really weird, look that https://ideone.com/XQXuTr and that https://ideone.com/NgZcJx

Comment: yes that's weird :https://ibb.co/bBe1t9

Comment: Damn,  put the space before %s like this `scanf(" %s", string1);` and try again

Comment: @FábioMorais nothing,the same thing

Comment: Put this `char string1[20]="abCd" ` and `char string2[20]="abcd "` and see if this works

Comment: i have tried but  the problem is stil there. is that the problem with compiler or something else?

Comment: yeah, maybe, go to `project-> build options` and select the `GNU GCC COMPILER`

Comment: go to `Edit->File encoding->system default`

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is that while receiving string from the user , you are storing the string using `scanf("%s",&string1)` , You need to understand that `&string1` and `string1` both gives the same address,but they both are very much different.When you increment `&string1` ,it points to 80 bytes further from the base address because on incrementing a pointer it points to the same location of its type ,`&string1` means base address of whole array while `string1` means address of the first element,so when you increment it ,it points to 4 bytes further from the base address.So when you give an address to scanf to store a string ,be careful what type of address you are giving otherwise it may give you some undefined behaviour.In your program just in place of `&string1` use `string1` in scanf to receive string, the remaining program is correct.